# Can't get Phpmyadmin

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, php, phpmyadmin

I recently installed Linux mint.But i can't get phpmyadmin when i hit `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`.I did the following commends
1)Install the LAMP Server using

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ -y
```

2)Set up mysql
3)Test Apache(success)
4)Install phpmyadmin using

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin -y
```

I didn't get any error while installation but when i hit `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` i get an error like

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the configuration path of phpmyadmin in apache

go to `/etc/apache2`

And `nano apache2.conf`

Add this lines after #Global configuration

```
# Include phpmyadmin configuration files to access it from browser
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

after that you need to restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: -Thanks a lot...Thank you very much .it's working

Comment: Oh the simple things.